# php/regex: separate feed data

Tags: php, regex

```
<description>&lt;img src='http://example.com/Pic_018_70x70.gif'&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;br /&gt;This is the content of the description.</description>
```

If I have images coming in the description field of a feed, how can I separate the image into a variable and strip the noise and have the description left too?

Comment: XML is perfect to use a XML parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the value of the img src attribute from the string in your question, and give you the text:

```
$sxml = new SimpleXMLElement(html_entity_decode($str));
$images = $sxml->xpath('//@src');
$text = $sxml->xpath('//description');

echo $images[0];  // http://example.com/Pic_018_70x70.gif
echo $text[0];    // This is the content of the description.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use  [simplexml](http://www.php.net/manual/de/simplexml.examples.php)

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
$description = $xml->description;
```

Comment: @streetparade - This results in $description being an empty string. Did you test this? And how does $xml = simplexml_load_string($string); differ from $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string); ?

Comment: Yes sure but then he should post the whole xml i think or?